# How do I select a date which appears more number of times in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

For eg:

Table is

```
date                      bill amount
12/06/2013                  200
12/06/2013                  920
15/06/2013                  300
```

And the output is

```
date                    bill amount
12/06/2013                  1120
15/06/2013                  300
```

Comment: View my posted answer includes SQLFiddle

Comment: Before writing serious queries just read "SQL for dummies" book, please.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21672/2)

```
 SELECT date, SUM(billamount)
   FROM tab1 GROUP BY date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *group by* to implement your target.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT theDate, COUNT(theDate) AS NumOccurrences

FROM someTable GROUP BY theDate

HAVING ( COUNT(theDate) > 1 )
```

Comment: That should be `sum()` not `count()`

Answer (score 0):

[**<kbd>sqlfiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/99e13/5)

```
select d as "date",
       sum(amount) as "bill amount", 
       count(*) as "count" 
from T
group by d
having count(*) > 0 --change zero to occurrence number you wish
order by d;
```

[**<kbd>sqlfiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/99e13/5)

[image]